# No local image path will show up in css background url

Tags: html, css, django, bootstrap-4

I have just overridden the bootstrap here and I made sure it's pulling from my local css, any other changes to it do work, but when I try to insert a background-image only localhost url for image works, if I specify local path it doesn't. I tried all variations, also static with background-image: url("{% static 'portfolio/waterfall.jpg' %}");
I'm using Django and had a problem earlier with my settings.py -can that be causing it?? Thanks
#settings.py

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

MEDIA_ROOT = BASE_DIR / 'media'

MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

#this is the jumbotron Im trying to get the background for

```
<section class="jumbotron text-center">
<div class="container">
  <h1>Album example</h1>
  <p class="lead text-muted">Something short and leading about the collection below—its contents, the 
creator, etc. Make it short and sweet, but not too short so folks don’t simply skip over it entirely. 
  </p>
  <p>
    <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary my-2">Main call to action</a>
    <a href="#" class="btn btn-secondary my-2">Secondary action</a>
  </p>
</div>
</section>
```

#and the custom .css

```
.jumbotron {
padding: 2rem 1rem;
margin-bottom: 2rem;
background-color: #c5b8b8;
border-radius: .3rem;
background-image: 
url("media/portfolio/images/foster-s-home-for-imaginary-friends-fosters-home-for-imaginary-friends-_ER46ne1.jpg");
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-position: bottom center;
background-size: cover;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Wrong  picture address, correct is https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Image_created_with_a_mobile_phone.png

Read about the license and available sizes and formats, then download and save on your server the appropriate version of the file for your site. Using direct link to particular version is possible, but it's rude to abuse wiki transfer.

---

edit
Did you insert a custom css **after** bootstrap in meta declarations?
If the url and order are not to blame then bad news - the problem is bigger and bootstrap-dependent.
Well, use https://validator.w3.org/unicorn/ and development tools in your browser to find out what is to blame

Comment: yea ok man, I didn't mean to abuse the server, picture in there is only example to demonstrate point. It doesn't solve my issue sadly

Comment: @doctorprofessor no offence, as new member you can get a lot of a priori hints and sometimes sermons too (for your own good); I've expanded my answer - I hope it helps